# How to modify the decimal precision in OpenERP?

Tags: openerp-7

I did some changes on field behavior of sale order line. I try to modify subtotal by changing its decimal precision into four, how ever the result is still on two decimal precision.
Example output: 1 X 87.5833 the result subtotal is 87.5800
Following is my code chunk:

```
<record forcecreate="True" id="base_prices" model="decimal.precision">
    <field name="name">Base Digits</field>
    <field name="digits">4</field>
</record>

class sale_order_line(osv.osv)
    ...
    'price_subtotal' : fields.function(_amount_line, string='Subtotal', digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Base Digits')),
    ...
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your example is not working, but there are few more options for you to do.

If you want to change specific field precision (and not mess with everything else) you could set on xml field instance precision (example from product/product_view.xml):

```
<field digits="(14, 3)" name="volume" attrs="{'readonly':[('type','=','service')]}"/>
```

Else, you could override/create your own field with specific decimal precision.

```
'product_uom_qty2': fields.float('Secondary uom value', digits=(3,3), help="Value that is received from converting primary UOM to secondary.")
```

Hope that helps :)